# How to inform user that change will take time to reflect?

Tags: error-message, copywriting, messages, messagebox

A form edit page works on the following logic:

If number of changes made during edit > original inputs, it can take up to 30 days for the changes to be reflected on the UI.

If the number of changes is < original inputs, it can take up to 7 days for the changes to be reflected.

How should I convey this message to the user? Is "You have made some changes. It can take up to 30 days for the change to be reflected on your interface." a good message?

**I'm primarily confused about 2 things:**
1. Should they be informed about the logic behind the ETA?
2. Is "...change to be reflected on your interface" an understandable phrase? Even if the user a is non-native english speaker?

Comment: That's way too long honestly. You can tell users that they have to wait a certain amount of time before they can see any changes, but the biggest issue is that they have to wait 30 days to begin with.

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail about the delays? And, by 'changes in the UI', does that mean there's functionality available, but not reflected in the UI? Some more details may help.

Comment: @Wanda Agreed. But it's something we can't change at the moment as the action deals with important data and a lot of dependencies between other 3rd party clients.  How should this be conveyed in a user friendly manner?

Comment: @MikeM The delays are due to SLAs between various clients. The delay in either case could also turn out to be under 7 days but the worst case scenario for one is 7 days and is 30 for the other. Basically, the message that I want to communicate to the user is - "Look, you made some changes, and the value 'x' you see on your dashboard **may** not be entirely correct (depending on your changes). The correct/verified value of x will be available to you in 7/30 days". Also, the value 'x' isn't a very important data. So an outdated value isn't a big problem to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is impossible to decrease the delay of the changes, I think it is very important to explain why the changes take so long. The user will be left with wondering why if you only give the duration of the delay.

> "You have made some changes. It can take up to 30 days for the change
>   to be reflected on your interface."

Is good, although you could change it to

> "You have made some changes. It can take up to 30 days for them to be visible."

or

> "Your changes are visible in 30 days. learn why **here**"

Explain very clearly why it takes this long and apologise for the delay.

I hope this helps.

Comment: All of those messages are *not* good because "... it is very important to explain why the changes take so long. The user will be left with wondering why if you only give the duration of the delay."  Users already know they've attempted to make changes, so giving that as a "reason" explains nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface should **show the current value, the pending value, and the ETA**.  As Hendrik describes, you can provide a link to the reason for the delay.  That reason should be much more clear than what you've provided.  "Basically, the message that [you] want to communicate" is a non-explanation that's equivalent to "Because I said so."